# Sourceforge and SVN

Tags: svn, sourceforge

I just added a local project to sourceforge. I moved some things around,
and imported via shell and netbeans. Now, when I browse the code online at
http://sourceforge.net/p/flamethyst/code/5/tree/
some files appear in multiple directories, (COPYING, README) and the "Flamethyst" directory should not be there at all.

If I move or remove a file from my local project and commit, should this not be reflected in the repository somewhere? Is there a way to browse the CURRENT files only, not older revisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not enough to just move or remove a file, you need to tell Subversion about it and commit that change to the repository. This can be done using the svn command line tool by doing `svn mv` for moving/renaming or `svn rm` for removing. Once you commit after that the changes should be visible on the web site. I'm not familiar with Netbeans but I'm sure that can be done there as well.

Comment: Thank you, that was it! Is there some commando to tell svn to add all new (to svn) files in a project to the version control? Sort of "addwhatisnotalreadyunderversioncontrol"...